# Way to Disable Cron log files BUT still send script output by email?

Tags: php, email, cron

Right now my cron job is running but it creates a new log file every time it runs, which is both ridiculous and unnecessary. What I want is a NO log file at all (I will never check them, and I don't want to have to go in and clean them up). If I set it to send an email it just sends an email saying it ran ok and the output of the script is contained in the log file.

BUT - I need to see the output of the PHP script it's executing as it contains success / fail information and in the future probably a list. If I have to I can just make the PHP script send an email instead of the CRON job, but can CRON send an email with the output of the script, yet create no log file?

With this command I've disabled emails but it still creates a new log file with the script output every time it runs:

```
wget *webaddress*/generate_late_fees.php >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Is this the only cron job on your system?
Are you reusing said PHP script? (if not, simply don't do any output and take care of sending mails in the script)

How cron job logging is handled is highly dependent on what system you're running and wether you're actually running a cron daemon or just systemd.timers

Turning logging off for individual cron jobs is nothing I've ever heard of, but you can disable cron logging altogether.

Comment: @Mastacheata No it's not, and yes the script is being reused (there is a link to manually initiate the script from the admin side). I already have the script determining how it's being run via a login check, so I still could have it send the email. I don't know details on the system... it's shared hosting so I don't have much control over it.

Answer (score 0):

In shared hosting you usually don't have any control over the syslog and cron daemon anyways, so there's no chance to turn off logging for that cronjob.

Just do the email stuff from within the script and don't rely on the crond's automatic output to email forwarding.
Another option is to do the email stuff from the console using the mail command. Just pipe wget's output to the mail command.

```
wget *webaddress*/generate_late_fees.php | mail -s "this is the subject" "to@address" >/dev/null 2>&1
```